# Bootstrap navbar customization

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a Bootstrap site and I found a site has this navbar design that I like. But I have no idea how did they make it or if it is possible to make in Bootstrap.

I don't need to have a exact same design, but here are something I want to achieve. 
1. vertical lines between items in navbar. 
2. when your mouse hover over to an item in navbar, the dropdown menu (not those words' alignment) would always align with the parent menu on the LEFT side.

[image]
[image]

The website is [here](http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb.html). 
Thanks so much!

Comment: What's the link to this site that you found this navbar?

Comment: use developer tools to look at css and html of that site.

Comment: @SimpleSandman, http://www.nga.gov/content/ngaweb.html

Comment: @ShuruiLiu -- Bootstrap is just css and you would restyle it to match, it would be easier, at least for me, to not use bootstrap's navbar and just use their dropdowns or use another menu system, like superclick (superfish's click version).

Answer (score 0):

For 1. vertical lines between items in navbar you need to do

As you can see they have an image on the #mainnav>li element ,

```
#mainnav>li {
background: url('../images/separator_medium.png') top left no-repeat;
float: left;
height: 68px;
padding: 0 1px;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

but you can do it with css , find your selector (if you dont know which one is it give me the link to your project)
and do

```
#mainnav>li {
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
-moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
-o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
}
```

if you don't want the last element to have a "line" just use the nth:last-child selector

For your second question give the dropdown menu an absolute position , this is their css , just adapt it to yours:

```
#mainnav .hover-nav {
display: none;
border: 5px solid #eee;
position: absolute;
top: 57px;
left: 1px;
background: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0 #333;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0 #333;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0 #333;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4,Direction=135,Color='#333333');
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4,Direction=135,Color='#333333');
width: auto;
min-width: 200px;
padding: 5px;
z-index: 998;
}
```

But I recommend to learn how to use the dev tools they can tell you everything you need about htmland css